# ggplot boxplot only shows one box instead of 10, how to fix?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

My data is in this format

```
    Responder_status variable value

 1. good             AHSP     0.01
 2. good             AHSP     1.16
 3. poor             AHSP     0.00
 4. good             HBB      0.25
```

It keeps going for all 10 variables, a row for each cell (792 cells). So in total I have 7920 rows. Here's the output of str.

```
'data.frame':   7920 obs. of  3 variables:
$ Responder_status: Factor w/ 3 levels "good","poor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ variable        : Factor w/ 10 levels "AHSP","APOC1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ value           : num  8.76 1.62 10.35 2.58 0 ...
```

When I plot a boxplot for it like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(variable), y=value))+ geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Responder_status)))
```

or like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(variable), y=value, fill=factor(Responder_status))) + geom_boxplot()
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

Why do I only get the box for my final variable and not for all of them (what I want)?

Comment: The other plots are box plots as well, there are just a lot of zeros for those groups. That means that all quartiles are 0 (hence the box is reduced to a line), and you are left with the outliers (the points).

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense. Any suggestions for showing the difference in the mean expression for my two groups? @Bas

Comment: Maybe taking a (pseudo-)log might help: `+ scale_y_continuous(scales = scales::pseudo_log_trans())`.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference unfortunately @Bas. Removing zeros is probably not a good idea either.

Comment: You can try to use a `geom_jitter` and give the points some `alpha` to show that there are a lot of zeros. If that doesn't work, you could try just calculating the means or doing something like `ggplot(data, aes(Responder_status, value, color = variable)) + geom_line() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")` to show how the means increase or decrease

Comment: I am not interested in the zeros, more in the difference between the two groups (poor and good). So I think I'll just plot the means for each group. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping `fill` inside the aesthetic function like below:

`library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(variable), y=value, fill=factor(Responder_status)))+
  geom_boxplot()`

Comment: This gives me the exact same result, I'll add it in the question